# quantity increase decrease display counter field

Tags: flutter, dart

New to flutter and tried several solutions I cannot get working for simple item counter
Example icons on row. 0 should increase decrease as i press icon +1 or -1
Donut    +1   0    -1

When I press plus_one icon button +1 it updates the print terminal so I know button is working.  if I  hot refresh the phone emulator the counter and display icon on phone updates to correct count.

How do I tell TextBox to update state ( show updated count on screen)  when counter has been increased  by  OnPress in IconBoxState?

'''

```
class _IconBoxState extends State<StatefulWidget> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Material(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Center(
            child: Ink(
              decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
                color: Colors.lightBlue,
                shape: CircleBorder(),
              ),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.plus_one),
                color: Colors.white,
                iconSize: 25,
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _counter += 10;
                    print('this is counter + $_counter');
                    //new TextBox(); not working....
                  });
                 
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class TextBox extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TextBoxState createState() => _TextBoxState();
}

class _TextBoxState extends State<TextBox> {
  // int _counter = 6;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            '$_counter',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      width: 50,
      height: 50,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        border: Border.all(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

'''

Comment: when you are setting the state with `setState` it only rebuilds the widget, where it is located and other widget's that the container widget contains, so in your case you have `TextBox` outside the `IconBox`, so only `IconBox` is rebuilt and textBox can't detect `state` change so it stays same, you have many ways to solve it. 1. somehow store both of the widget inside the container widget and rebuild the state of the container widget, you can do this, 2. use `provider`, 3. use `InheritedWidget` 4. use `BloC`.

Answer (score 1):

when you are setting the state with `setState` it only rebuilds the widget, where it is located and other widget's that the container `widget` contains, so in your case you have `TextBox` outside the `IconBox`, so only `IconBox` is rebuilt and `TextBox` can't detect state change so it stays same, you have many ways to solve it. 1. somehow store both of the widget inside the container `widget` and rebuild the state of the container `widget`, you can do this, 2. use `provider`, 3. use `InheritedWidget` 4. use `BloC`

This is a full code of version one, so you can play around, You will need to include `ContainerWidget` inside the page you want it to be displayed or in the `Scaffold` of `MaterialApp`:

```
class ContainerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ContainerWidgetState createState() => _ContainerWidgetState();
}

class _ContainerWidgetState extends State<ContainerWidget> {
  int counter = 0;

  void increase() {
    counter += 1;
  }

  void decrease() {
    counter -= 1;
  }

  @override
  void setState(fn) {
    super.setState(fn);
  }

  stateSetter(String event) {
    if (event == "increase") {
      increase();
      setState(() {});
    } else if (event == "decrease") {
      decrease();
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          TextBox(
            counter: counter,
          ),
          IconBox(
            containerSetState: stateSetter,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class IconBox extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function containerSetState;

  IconBox({this.containerSetState});

  @override
  _IconBoxState createState() => _IconBoxState();
}

class _IconBoxState extends State<IconBox> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Material(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Center(
            child: Ink(
              decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
                color: Colors.lightBlue,
                shape: CircleBorder(),
              ),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.plus_one),
                color: Colors.white,
                iconSize: 25,
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    widget.containerSetState("increase");
                    //new TextBox(); not working....
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Material(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Center(
            child: Ink(
              decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
                color: Colors.lightBlue,
                shape: CircleBorder(),
              ),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.exposure_minus_1),
                color: Colors.white,
                iconSize: 25,
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    widget.containerSetState("decrease");
                    //new TextBox(); not working....
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class TextBox extends StatefulWidget {
  final int counter;

  TextBox({this.counter});

  @override
  _TextBoxState createState() => _TextBoxState();
}
```

Comment: thank you for suggestions.  i did your suggestions and put the icons in the same  container and make the set state point  + -   methods at top of the same class.   all seem to work now.